# drupal form submission

Tags: forms

I have a very weird problem, my custom forms submition doesn't work unless devel module is active.
any ideas how to solve this problem?

```
function forexCompare_form_submit($form,&$form_state){

$array = unserialize(variable_get('forexCompare_company1',""));

$array[] = t($_POST['forexCompare_company1']);
variable_set('forexCompare_company1',serialize($array));
//drupal_set_message(print_r($form_state)." k".$_POST['forexCompare_company1']);
}

function forexCompare_form($form,&$form_state){
return array(
            'forexCompare_company1' => array(
                '#type' => 'select',
                '#title' => 'Company #1',
                '#options' => getCompanies()
            ),
            'forexCompare_company2' => array(
                '#type' => 'select',
                '#title' => 'Company #2',
                '#options' => get_stored_comp()
            ),
            'submit' => array(
                '#type' => 'submit',
                '#value' => 'Save',
            ),
            '#submit' => array(
               'forexCompare_form_submit'
            )

);
}
```

i have notice that when i return the drupal_get_form() on the page callback , but when i pass it as variable in theme function doesnt work

```
function userOptions_theme(){
global $user;
$user_loaded = user_load($user->uid);
return array(
  'settings_user_transfer'=>array(
      'template' => 'setting',
      'variables' => array('money' => $user_loaded,'form' => drupal_get_form('userOptions_form'))
  )
);
}
```

Comment: I don't have the answer to your question, but I want to mention that directly inserting $_POST values in your database doesn't seem like a good idea. Use `$form_state['values']` when processing submitted values in a submit handler.

Comment: @marcvangend +1. Seems you're using some templates. Make sure you're not missing the from_id, form_token in template.

Comment: actually i use drupal_render($form), do i still have to render these elements individually too.

Comment: i have a feeling that you cant pass form as a variable in template

Comment: @RamySelim normally you don't have to use `drupal_render($form)`; you just return the output of [drupal_get_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7) in a menu callback. See [form_example.module](http://api.drupal.org/api/examples/form_example!form_example.module/7) for an example.

Comment: @marcvangend yea but i want to pass it to template along with other stuff

Comment: Also, you shouldn't really be using camel case for your functions with Drupal.  [Drupal Coding Standards](http://drupal.org/coding-standards#naming).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong with your approach, don't use $_POST, the values are there in &$form_state and you will break Drupal form handling using $_POST. If you have devel running use dpm() to explore that array.

In the theme function call drupal_get_form with the right name: forexCompare_form, i.e. 
drupal_get_form('forexCompare_form'). Or was the theme function just an example.

Answer (score 0):

As marcvangend said, I dont have to use `drupal_render()` inside the template, and now i know why the forms was working when devel module is active, becuase it was building the theme register on every page request.

Thank you all for your help